# Yosef's dreams and time

Tags: pentateuch-chumash, yosef, dream

I had an interesting idea, and I wondered if anyone knows of sources that use it.
Yosef deals with three sets of dreams: his own, the dreams of the sommelier and baker, and the dreams of Pharaoh. In the last two sets, repetition means time. By the sommelier and baker, Yosef says that the three branches are three days (Genesis 40:12) and the three baskets are three days (40:18): the events he describes will happen then. By Pharaoh's dreams, the seven cows or the seven ears of corn are seven years (41:26), and again the events will happen after that time.
But Yosef's second dream also had repetition: eleven stars, and the sun and the moon. I know that Yaakov Avinu interpreted that as having to do with eleven brothers and Yosef's father and his "mother". But I wonder if it might also have to do with time. Yosef was 17 years old (37:2), and in 11+2 years he'd be thirty, which is how old he was (41:46) when Pharaoh appointed him over Egypt and everyone bowed to him (not his brothers, not for several more years). Also, he *should* have been appointed two years earlier, after just eleven years, as the Midrash says.
His first dream doesn't mention numbers so I wouldn't know what to do with it.
Anyhow, does this idea appear anywhere?

Comment: The *chiluk* you have pointed out reminds me of a Gra which Rav Hutner is fond of quoting on וְעִנּוּ אֹתָם אַרְבַּע מֵאוֹת שָׁנָה - וְדוֹר רְבִיעִי יָשׁוּבוּ הֵנָּה - that *talah ha'kilkul be'meshech ha'zman ve'hatikun be'hemeshech ha'doros*.

Comment: Beautiful הערה!

Comment: I'd mention as a point against, that later when Yosef sees his brothers, the Torah says that he remembered _the dreams_. I don't see how that fits with this interpretation.

Comment: The time spans are appropriate for each dream. Paro's birthday was in three days and it was based on events happening immediately. Paro's dream was based on seven cycles of crops so of course each cow or each grain stalk was one cycle of crop growth (a year). Rav Hirsch says each dream was internally consistant. The other dreams do not have to do with specific time periods.

Comment: @sabbahillel "The other dreams do not have to do with specific time periods." How do you know that? I gave a relevant time period for one of those early dreams. The time periods you're giving don't seem that obvious to me, except after hearing Yosef's interpretation. A cow doesn't immediately say to me, a year.

Comment: A crop of grain implies a growth season which is a year. A cow is born at a particular time of the year. Of course it required Yosef to realize this. Par'o and his wise men did not realize this at first but were struck by the realization that it was so once Yosef gave the interpretation. Rav Hirsch points out that they understood the dreams and their meanings upon hearing Yosef's statements. That is why they accepted what he said as wise and understanding.

Comment: In Be'er Mayim Chaim to Bereshit 37:6 quoting Zohar, it says that these 1st two dreams were meant to be fulfilled immediately, but were delayed for 22 years because Yosef told the dream twice to his 11 brothers.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but the problem is if it meant years, it should have been all the same thing, not eleven stars plus the sun and moon.

Comment: @N.T. I think I answered that? "Also, he should have been appointed two years earlier, after just eleven years, as the Midrash says."

Comment: @MichoelR So why a sun and a moon both?

Comment: Good question, I think!

Comment: @YaacovDeane _Why_ would you change "the butler" in my question to "the sommelier"? I don't even know what that means, and who says it's the correct pshat in שר המשקים? It adds a twist into my question that probably doesn't belong there. Also, it makes me sound like the kind of person who knows what that word means.

Comment: @MichoelR The term "Sommelier" is the person in a restaurant who is in charge of the wine and their service also known as the "Chief Wine Steward". The Hebrew term שר-המשקים, like used in Bereshit 40:9 is referring to a sommelier specifically, like his dream recounts in Bereshit 40:10-11. The Hebrew for "butler" is משרת, which is not used in the text. If you come across a Hebrew term in the Chumash that you aren't sure of regarding its meaning, the best practice is to look it up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### בָּרוּךְ שֶׁכִּוַּנְתָּ

The [צרור המור](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30801&st=&pgnum=100&hilite=) provides this explanation, albeit with some variations:

> And behold Hashem showed Yosef two things [in the second dream]: one the fulfillment of what he saw in the first dream, second  the number of years in which his domination will come into fruition. To explain, in the first dream he saw his domination and its cause. In this dream he saw the timing, which comes from the sun and moon. This is why the verse specifically singles out the sun and moon but leaves the eleven stars general. **So this dream is coming to inform Yosef that the peace, ruling, and interpretation of the dream will be after thirteen years -- equal to the two luminaries plus the eleven stars.**

[image]

Comment: Whoa. Thank you!